# Tridion Vs SiteCore

Tags: 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion, sites-9

We are currently on 2013 and in process of migrating to Site9. But company has second thought on SiteCore as CMS. Can someone lay out a few key differences between SiteCore and Tridion? And possible reasons to stick with Tridion?
Second question on same topic, what all are the implications if we don't migrate to Site 9 and continue using the Tridion 2013 ?

Answer (score 4):

As [posted in this announcement](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/product-announcements/posts/sdl-tridion-2013-sp1-hr1-standard-support-extended-to-december-31-2019), SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 became out of Standard Support as of December 31, 2019. Any issues encountered for the year following would be addressed on a best-effort basis and only if your organization has an agreement in place with SDL.

Refer to the [SDL Product Lifecycle](https://www.sdl.com/support/) for the support policy, which explains Extended Support with the following.

> **Extended Support**
>   No further Service Patches or general Hot Fixes will be issued. Support will be given on a
>   best effort basis. Note: Access to this stage will require an additional support agreement
>   between SDL customer support and the customer to be have been agreed.

I believe your question on the difference between products is a bit too broad in a Stack Exchange Q&A (akin to asking about, say, the difference between .NET and Java). :-)

However, I'd highlight that SDL Tridion is a strong fit if you manage a large number of sites or channels with varying delivery (output) requirements. I'd suggest continuing with Tridion Sites if you have varying requirements from internal and external stakeholders, strong integration needs, and/or multilingual, multi-regional, or compliance requirements.

Finally, recent and future releases of the product have focused on the editorial and implementer experience. Though specific features like a GraphQL content delivery end-point, JAVA or .NET integrations in Content Management or Delivery, or the upcoming new user interface, may or may not appeal to your organization based on your needs. :-)

Answer (score 2):

well, that's a pretty open question and depends very much on the requirements/expectations of the client (business and technical).

Perhaps it would be best for you check a few of the many blogs out there and then to write a blog proposing your thoughts - then any technical questions can be posited in this forum?

Answer (score 2):

Agree with both Alvin and Mark, it's a very broad topic and depends on what exactly you need/want ***"Know Your Needs"*** and on that note, here is a quick link which might interest you..
https://manishmehmood.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/sdl-tridion-sites-vs-aem-vs-sitecore-which-one-is-better/